How to navigate to an iOS custom keyboard's container app and then back to the app using your custom keyboard?
I'm trying to recreate the functionality seen in the ScanKey app
In this custom keyboard you can click a keyboard button which launches the parent container app which has all sorts of scanning functions and then navigates back to to the previous app. This previous app can be any app.
I have figured out how to launch my container app with url schemes. I'm currently using this approach
// Usage:
// UIInputViewController.openURL(NSURL(string: "your-app-scheme://")!)
extension UIInputViewController {

    func openURL(url: NSURL) -> Bool {
        do {
            let application = try self.sharedApplication()
            return application.performSelector("openURL:", withObject: url) != nil
        }
        catch {
            return false
        }
    }

    func sharedApplication() throws -> UIApplication {
        var responder: UIResponder? = self
        while responder != nil {
            if let application = responder as? UIApplication {
                return application
            }

            responder = responder?.nextResponder()
        }

        throw NSError(domain: "UIInputViewController+sharedApplication.swift", code: 1, userInfo: nil)
    }

}

But I can't figure out how to return to the app using my keyboard?
I noticed the more I used ScanKey that even if I closed the calling app, then performed the scan, ScanKey would actually launch the calling app from its closed state. I'm struggling to find a way to capture the calling app's url scheme though I'm not sure that's possible.

did you able to make happen to go back to custom keyboard again?

@im07, I just posted the solution that worked for me.

This is what I ended up doing.
When I launch the container app from the keyboard, I capture the bundleId of the app using the keyboard.
extension KeyboardViewController {
var hostBundleId: String? {
    if let id = hostBundleIdValueBefore16 { return id }
    return hostBundleIdValueFor16
}

private var hostBundleIdValueBefore16: String? {
    let value = parent?.value(forKey: "_hostBundleID") as? String
    return value != "<null>" ? value: nil
}

private var hostBundleIdValueFor16: String? {
    guard let pid = parent?.value(forKey: "_hostPID") else { return nil }
    let selector = NSSelectorFromString("defaultService")
    guard let anyClass: AnyObject = NSClassFromString("PKService"),
       let pkService = anyClass as? NSObjectProtocol,
       pkService.responds(to: selector),
       let serverInis = pkService.perform(selector).takeUnretainedValue() as? NSObjectProtocol
    else { return nil }
    let lities = serverInis.perform(NSSelectorFromString("personalities")).takeUnretainedValue()
    let bundleId = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier ?? ""
    guard let infos = lities.object(forKey: bundleId) as? AnyObject,
       let info = infos.object(forKey: pid) as? AnyObject,
       let con = info.perform(NSSelectorFromString("connection")).takeUnretainedValue() as? NSObjectProtocol
    else { return nil }
    let xpcCon = con.perform(NSSelectorFromString("_xpcConnection")).takeUnretainedValue()
    let handle = dlopen("/usr/lib/libc.dylib", RTLD_NOW)
    let sym = dlsym(handle, "xpc_connection_copy_bundle_id")
    typealias xpcFunc = @convention(c) (AnyObject) -> UnsafePointer<CChar>
    let cFunc = unsafeBitCast(sym, to: xpcFunc.self)
    let response = cFunc(xpcCon)
    let hostBundleId = NSString(utf8String: response)
    return hostBundleId as String?
}
}

Then I saved that to my shared app storage by utilizing app groups between the keyboard and container app.
When I'm ready to return to the app using the keyboard, I set another app storage to store the text input. Then I get the bundleID and launch the app based on the bundleID.
func sendTextToHost(text: String){
    UserDefaults(suiteName: "group name")!.set(text, forKey: "text")
    if let bundleId = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group name")!.string(forKey: "your key"){
        guard let obj = objc_getClass("LSApplicationWorkspace") as? NSObject else {return }
        let workspace = obj.perform(Selector(("defaultWorkspace")))?.takeUnretainedValue() as? NSObject
        _ = workspace?.perform(Selector(("openApplicationWithBundleID:")), with: bundleId) != nil
        UserDefaults(suiteName: "group name")!.removeObject(forKey: "hostBundleId")
        
    }

}

